# if $x\in Q_p$ and $x\neq 0$ then there exixts $x^{-1}\in Q_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Show that if $x\in Q_p$ and $x\neq 0$ then there exixts $x^{-1}\in Q_p$

I tried to constuct a y such that xy=1. By the definition of $Q_p$, $x=a_{-l}p^{-l}+a_{-l+1}p^{-l+1}+...$ and I want to find $ (b_{-l},b_{-l+1},...)$ such that $xy=(a_{-l}p^{-l}+a_{-l+1}p^{-l+1}+...)(b_{-l}p^{-l}+b_{-l+1}p^{-l+1}+...)=1$ But It turns out that this cannot be solved.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb{Q}_p$, the $p$-adic rationals?

Comment: Basically every definition of $\mathbb Q_p$ immediately yields that it is a field. I am confused by that question.

Comment: Hint: The expansion of $y$ should begin from the power $p^\ell$. In other words
$$y=b_\ell p^\ell+b_{\ell+1}p^{\ell+1}+\cdots.$$

Comment: If $l\gt 0$ you should get $b_{-l}=0$ etc just by looking at the most negative/least positive index. Working through, you get the first non-zero coefficient for $b_l$ as @JyrkiLahtonen notes. So I'm not sure why you say "this cannot be solved"

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I got your idea. If we let $b_{-l},...b_{l-1}$ be 0 just like you said, additionally I make $b_{l+1},...$ be 0, then the only term remains is $a_lb_lp^0 =1$  and I got $b_l=a_{-l}^{-1}$. But I need $b_l\in \{1,2,...,p-1\}$.